# Using a promisified mongodb to find multiple documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

Working on a node.js server retrieving data from my mongoDB database but its getting a bit unwieldy and would like to use promises mainly because I've never used them before and would like the insight but also to clean up the code. I'm using the `bluebird` module in node to promisify mongodb and can currently view one item.

```
var client = MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://localhost:27017/stockData')
.then(function(db) {
  return db.collection("stockData").findOneAsync({ High:  253.41796296683228 })
})
.then(function(doc) { 
console.log(doc)
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err)
});
```

however I would like to be able to loop through multiple docs using a cursor however I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the whole thing and would like to convert this chunk of code here to use promises.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){ //set up connection to mongodb takes two parameters a url for the db and a callback function 

        assert.equal(err,null) //check to see if there any errors connecting to the database
        var cursor = db.collection('stockData').find().limit(10) // cursor will be an array of objects retrieved from the database
        cursor.forEach(function(doc, err){ //loop through the cursor
            assert.equal(null,err) //check for errors
            console.log(doc)
        }, function(){ 
            db.close(); //close the database once the query is finished
        });
    });
```

Help in this matter would be greatly appreciated especially if you could explain whats going on so I could get a good handle of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var MongoClient = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));

MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
  .then(function (db){
    return db.collection('stockData').find({}, { limit: 10 }).toArrayAsync()
      .then(function (docs) {
        if (docs.length > 0) {
          docs.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        db.close();
      })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you really sure that `.connectAsync()` continues with a `function (err, db)` function? That's exactly the kind of thing that promises would *not* typically do.

Comment: I tried it your way Luis however the promise keeps returning rejected, the db parameter is undefined

Comment: I'm so sorry, I posted it without checking it. I have updated it now. @CraigHyland

Comment: Edited again. Now it works. So you need to apply the `toArray` function after a `find`; in this case, the async function to use is `toArrayAsync()` rather than `findAsync()`.

Comment: Sorry to ask this so late Luis, but why there an empty `{}` in the `findAsync()` method? also if I wanted to sort the query by any order would I include the sort in the `findAsync()` method just like you did with `limit: 10` ?

Comment: If you check the documentation for `find`, https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find, the first argument is the query, the second can be either the fields to project or the options. In this case, we're passing the options, and since we need to do this in the second argument, the query has to be an empty object `{}`. To pass sort options, you'd append it to the second argument, like `{ limit: 10, sort: { field: 1 } }`.